# Could not find driver MySQL with hhvm

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-4, hhvm

I am using Laravel with HHVM.

MySQL is working in normal controller functions.

But whenever from Commands (artisan), DB connection of MySQL (PDO) is initialised, then error comes of "could not find driver".

Also I have tried writing connection initialisation from Controller function and calling it from Command still same error comes.

```
$conn = new \PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have not installed php-mysql driver

Try installing by using following command

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-mysql
```

Comment: This is better than my answer as I assumed the module was installed in the first place. This also only works with debian/ubuntu systems, but for the "hat" style OS's, just swap `apt-get` for `yum`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the PDO mysql driver is enabled.

If you're running debian/ubuntu, you can check like this

```
$ php -i | grep pdo
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, # <-- This line
pdo_mysql
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

And if it's not enabled, you can enable it with:

```
$ php5enmod pdo_mysql
```

For other operating systems, you'll have to check the documentation.

Don't forget to restart your web server (Apache, or other).

Comment: actually it is running from Route controllers and and not from Command

Comment: Then check `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Note that if you're running debian/ubuntu then the above likely works. If you're running something else that separates which modules are used by cli and server, then you just need to check the appropriate place.